# Python / Spyder - Contourf() animation questions. Speed and Colorbar.

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I am new to python and recently was able to generate a contourf animation. I know how to generate a colorbar, however I'm unsure as to how to implement a colorbar into the animation.

Also, is there a way to speed up the animation process?

My data is taken from an oscilloscope in a plane of measurement. Each location in the plane of measurement is stored as a file, where the file name is the location of measurement.

Below is my code.

```
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.animation as animation 
# import pylab won't import animation

dr = 4;
dz = 4;

rStart = -72;
rEnd = 72;
zStart = -20;
zEnd = -236;

datatype = dtype('>d')

rspace = arange(rStart,rEnd+dr,dr)
zspace = arange(zStart,zEnd-dz,-dz)
tspace = 1000000 # number of samples

directory = 'D:\OscopeData\\'
data = zeros([len(zspace),len(rspace),tspace], dtype=datatype)

for j in range(0,len(zspace)):
    for i in range(0,len(rspace)):
        r = 'R' +  str(rStart + dr(i))
        z = 'Z' +  str(zStart - dz(j))
        datafile = directory + r + z  + 'Ch1.dat'       
        data[j][i] = fromfile(datafile, dtype = datatype)

fig,ax = subplots()
textsize = 30

def animate(t):
    ax.clear
    ax.contourf(data[:,:,t],50)
    title('Plot Title', fontsize = textsize + 6)
    xlabel('R axis', fontsize = textsize)
    ylabel('Z axis', fontsize = textsize)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,50,blit=False)
```